# How to create a slanted div with a background image applied?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a slanted div with a background image. [HERE](http://prntscr.com/cf95f8) is a screenshot of what I am trying to achieve.

I have always made my slanted divs using css triangles. However I am finding this technique troublesome in this situation because it is 2 separate parts and the pictures wont connect.

As of right now in my code I have a div with the background image applied with a before element that looks like this:

```
#booking-form:before{
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: -320px;
    border-top: 726px solid transparent;
    border-right: 320px solid $secondary;
}
```

This makes the triangle I am looking for however if I add an image to the triangle it fills the entire before css and looks like [this](http://prntscr.com/cf99zq):

But I need it to look like the [original](http://prntscr.com/cf95f8).

Any suggestions? Thank you!

Comment: CSS transforms, skew.

Answer (score 0):

Just use a full width div with a suitably angled gradient background instead.

No transforms, no borders.

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
}
.content {
  height: 150px;
  padding: 20px 0;
  background: linear-gradient(-65deg, rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.5) 65%, transparent 65%);
  display: flex;
}
div {
  background-image: url(http://www.fillmurray.com/460/300);
}
form {
  width: 50%;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.85);
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="content">
    <form action=""></form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately not avalaible everywhere, [mix-blend-mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/mix-blend-mode) could be an hint using gradients to choose wich parts to blend

```css
body {
  height: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(110deg, white 45%, transparent 45%), url(http://lorempixel.com/800/600/city/3) right no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 100%, 75% auto ;
  margin: 0;
}

html {
  height: 100%;
  min-width:800px;
  margin: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(110deg, transparent 45%, darkcyan 45%), url(http://lorempixel.com/800/600/city/2)top left no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 100%, 75% auto;
}

body {
  mix-blend-mode: overlay;
}
/* demo purpose */
body>div {
  padding:1px;
  padding-left: 55%;
  color: black;
}
body>p {
  margin:0;
  }
/* small snippet view purpose */
html, body {
background-attachment:fixed;
}
```

```html
<p> nop, mix-blend-mode is not avalaible here :( </p>
<div>
  <h2 name="Summary" id="Summary">Summary<a class="button section-edit only-icon" href="/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/mix-blend-mode$edit#Summary"><i aria-hidden="true" class="icon-pencil"></i><span>Edit</span></a></h2>

  <p>The <strong><code>mix-blend-mode</code></strong> CSS property describes how an element's content should blend with the content of the element that is below it and the element's background.</p>

  <p></p>
  <table class="properties">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row"><a href="/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/initial_value">Initial value</a></th>
        <td><code>normal</code></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">Applies to</th>
        <td>all HTML elements</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row"><a href="/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/inheritance">Inherited</a></th>
        <td>no</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">Media</th>
        <td>visual</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row"><a href="/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/computed_value">Computed value</a></th>
        <td>as specified</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">Animation type</th>
        <td>discrete</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">Canonical order</th>
        <td>the unique non-ambiguous order defined by the formal grammar</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">Creates <a href="/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context">stacking context</a></th>
        <td>yes</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```